# Did gmaps4rails ver 1.4.6 break the auto_adjust option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

My maps with single or multiple markers, each with a circle, all use auto_adjust.

Logging a gmaps call with a single marker to the console, I get:

```
gmaps( :map_options => {:auto_adjust=>true, :auto_zoom=>true}, :markers => {:data=>"[{\"lat\":43.5368851,\"lng\":-79.6849913}]"}, :circles => {:data=>"[{\"lng\":-79.6849913,\"lat\":43.5368851,\"radius\":5000.0,\"strokeColor\":\"#DD3300\"}]", :options=>{:fillOpacity=>0.35}} )
```

No problems in ver 1.4.5, but in ver's 1.4.6 through the newest 1.4.8 the maps do not auto-adjust and instead center at (latitude, longitude) = (0,0).

I assume the 1.4.6 update broke something, or is there another change that I've missed? Thanks!

Comment: I just upgraded to 1.4.8 now, and auto_adjust is working fine here, so I don't know what's happening. Any js errors? auto_adjust defaults to true btw.

Comment: It's ok to post on Stackoverflow, it probably benefits to more people than github, and we can say "thank you" with +1 ;) But you might want to post on both sites.

Comment: really weird. Did you touch anything in the js? what's your full ruby call to `gmaps`?

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue.  Had to downgrade gmaps4rails to 1.4.5.  My view call is `    = gmaps(:markers => {:data => @json}, :map_options => { :detect_location => true, :auto_zoom => false, :zoom => 15, :auto_adjust => true, :center_on_user => true})
`  Looking forward to get any answers on this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Robin.  No, apneadiving, I didn't touch anything in the js.  I've added my full call to the question. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Sorry guys, I can't reproduce, both lines of codes work on my localhost. I can't understand what's happening here. MMmmmm, or maybe one thing: did you reinstall fresh assets after upgrading gmaps4rails? (@Godsaur concerned)

Comment: Isn't auto_adjust in contradiction with setting the zoom? I feel like it would make sense if auto_adjust did nothing.

Comment: Aha! That's it, @apneadiving.  Thanks!  Add that answer, and I'll accept it.  :-)  I didn't realize I needed to update gmaps4rails' assets after every install/update.  Running 'rails generate gmaps4rails:install` fixed this issue.

Note that v1.4.6 still does behave exactly as I describe (with updated assets), but v1.4.7 fixed it (if the assets are also updated).

Comment: @Robin No, auto_adjust automatically determines where your map is centered, independent of the zoom.

Comment: @Robin: yep my intention was to let dev decide the zoom level with the map center adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply rerun the command to install the fresh assets from the gem :)

```
rails generate gmaps4rails:install
```